# Two var interpolation

Tags: interpolation, python

I've been trying to find (unsuccesfully) a method to interpolate a two-var scalar field, preferably using Python or Matlab.
I have a relatively large set of data which follows no recognizable pattern.
I tried some SciPy library methods (RectBivariateSplin, interp2d) but none of them exactly fits my needs, either because they require specially organized data or because the output is given graphically, while I need the numerical expression of the result.

Are there any books or materials you could refer me to?

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered using a K-d tree?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will read about them.